# I need to get only testpath1 and store this in a variable

Tags: python, excel, csv

[image]

My code:

```
import csv

with open("C:/Users/users/Desktop/tst/test.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print("line[0])
```

but that prints only `testpath1` – `testpath4`.

Comment: Just call `next()` one more time — no need for the `for line in…` loop.

Comment: Huh and how do I get the line when there is no for line? So how do I print it @martineau

Comment: I meant you could do it like this: `line = next(csv_reader)`. It will give you the first row following the header row you skipped with the first call to `next()`. After that, just `print(line[0])`.

Comment: Thank you verry much, that helped me a lot. Have a nice day! @martineau